# How to circumvent client side validation in this particular situation

Tags: jquery, html, validation, javascript

I want to preface this question by saying I know that client side validation is always necessary, but I want to know this anyway.

Assume the following:

I have a form

```
<form id="update_form" action="/App/appManage/" method="post">
     <input name="data[test]" value="1" type="text" id="AppModified"/> 
</form>
```

And a submit button OUTSIDE of the form.

```
<a id="update_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium">Update</a>
```

This button submits via the following Jquery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#update_button").click(function() {
       $("#update_form").submit();
    });
  });


//Form Validation
$("#update_form").validate({
    rules: {
        "data[test]": "required"
    },
    messages: {
        "data[test]": "Please enter a value for this field"
    }
});

</script>
```

There is no ajax involved.

If a user disables javascript and clicks the update button no action takes place. (tested)

If the user hits enter in any of the fields on the form, it does not submit the form (tested)

If the user has javascript enabled and clicks update and the input field is left blank they are not able to submit the form and a message flashes under the field asking you to please fill it out (tested)

On submit the form saves the value entered in the input field to my database.

My question is:

How can someone get a blank value for that field in my database?

P.S. I know there is probably a way, but I want to know what it is!  I don't know what to know how to improve my code, or be told that I should be using server side validation to ensure that it's not blank before inserting the record into my database, simply what a malicious user would do verbatim to circumvent my code here.

Just so everyone knows, through a friend I discovered another way to circumvent this type of validation.  You can just create the submit element yourself in firebug and submit the form with the field blank like that.

Comment: With AJAX? Validate the form in JS first and when it's all good send an AJAX request and check the info on the server.

Comment: Client side validation is *never* necessary. It is always optional and serves no other purpose than usability enhancement (the user does not need to submit the form and wait for response of the server). The real validation, that determines whether user data is allowed to hit the database, has to be done on the server.

Comment: There is no ajax involved in this.  The form submits and saves the input in a database.  I don't understand these comments about how the user would submit the form with no value entered for the input.

Comment: The result of a form submit is a piece of **text** information together with a http header (which is again just **text**) and sent over a TCP socket to a specific address. It's not difficult to write a simple program that just creates such a result without opening your web form at all or to use a program like Fiddler that allows to build POST requests manually and send it to the server. This circumvents your whole website and client side validation. You can only catch and validate such a potentially malicious request input on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anybody can send an HTTP POST to your site with invalid data. They do not need to use your web page at all. There a thousands of tools to accomplish that. For example with the build in JavaScript debugger of a web browser you can easily send

```
$("#submit").trigger('click')
```

without passing validation first. As Oswald pointed out, server side validation is the king. Client side validation is not for security but for user experience.

Comment: Thanks, best answer yet.  If you could elaborate verbatim the steps I could do in order to actually do what you suggested here as a test?  Also, are there any other methods to circumvent this code?  Thanks.  I'm asking because I may use this method on an intranet website where this type of validation may be good enough for my needs, depending on the results of this research.

Comment: Use the command line tool curl http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html:      'curl --data "data[test]=evildata" http://www.mysite.org/form.php'